# Why are there so many different symbols to represent the Heaviside (unit step) function

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, terminology, math-history, signal-processing

In signal processing, the unit step function is typically written as $u(t)$. In other references though I have seen it represented as $H(t)$ and even $\theta(t)$. The unit impulse is fairly ubiquitously represented as $\delta(t)$. Why the inconsistency in giving the unit step function a symbolic representation?

Comment: $1_{[0,\infty)}$.